# Can someone explain to me the reversing of Doubly Linked List given a head node?

Tags: algorithm

I've looked at other solutions but I've had a hard time visualizing the effect.
I understand that we have to switch the .next and the .prev but i don't understand why we are iterating to .prev

So for example:
Given Null--->A--><--B---><---C---><--D-->Null

If head is A

We set a variable "traverse" to head

while traverse != Null...

1) temp = traverse.prev

2) traverse.prev = traverse.next

3) traverse.next = temp

4) (Confusing part) ** traverse = traverse.prev?

So in our given setup, after the first iteration it would be...

B--><--A-->Null ,  C---><--->D--->Null

Given this, I can't visualize the second iteration and beyond if B is traverse, we end up swapping C and A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After steps `1`, `2` and `3`, next node to process of the original list is pointed now by `traverse.prev` since `next` and `prev` were swapped.

After the first iteration `A.next` is `null` and `A.prev` is pointing to `B`, but `B.prev` is still pointing to `A` and `B.next` is pointing to `C`.

After second iteraction `B.prev` is pointing to `C` and `B.next` is pointing to `A`.

So, on each interation you fix references of a single node and move to the next of the original list (now targeted by `prev`).

Comment: Ok it makes more sense now. The pointers are acting in a "circular fashion".

Comment: It didnt make much sense to me where A.prev is B and B.prev is A after the first iteration

Comment: Yes, this is fixed during the process. On each iteration only one node is handled

Answer (score 2):

You have swapped the prev/next of A, but haven't touched B, so B must still be

```
A<--B-->C
```

and you will be pointing at b, so I think the next iteration you will swap b's prev/next pointers, then go to c (which, after the switch, will be b.prev)...  I assume when you are done you will return a pointer to "traverse" which will be the new head (D).

Note that between any two iterations the list will be messed up (invalid) because in a valid list node.next.prev must be node for every object except the last but after the first iteration, A.next will be null and A.prev.prev will be a which is just not right.

Since the list is invalid, you will not be able to use your simple ascii notation to visualize it anymore, it assumes that node.next.prev=node always holds.

A valid notation might be:

Initial:

```
Null<--A-->B  A<--B-->C  B<--C-->D  C<--D-->Null
       ^
     Traverse
```

After first ieration:

```
B<--A-->Null  A<--B-->C  B<--C-->D  C<--D-->Null
            ^     ^
            ^   Traverse
            ^
        Temporarily 
         invalid.
```

Using this new notation, try it again.

Also I would move the "While" condition to the end and make it:

```
While (traverse.prev != null)
```

This way you are still holding a pointer to traverse pointing to the new head (Which you can return to the caller), otherwise all you have is a pointer to the tail (the original head) which isn't very interesting now.

Wow, I spent way more effort on that answer than I should have--but I love data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Given the double linked list

```
NULL<-A<=>B<=>C<=>D->NULL
```

And your algorithm

```
traverse = A

while traverse != Null...
  temp          = traverse.prev    // [1]
  traverse.prev = traverse.next    // [2]
  traverse.next = temp             // [3]
  traverse      = traverse.prev    // [4]
```

The lines `[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]` swap the previous and the next node of traverse. Let's say it's your first iteration, just before the fourth line your chain is :

```
        +----------+
        |          | A.prev
        |          V
(traverse = A) <-- B <=> C <=> D -> NULL
        |
        | A.next
        v
      NULL
```

So, when your fourth line is executed, `traverse` becomes `A.prev` which means `B` and you move on.